# Problem in listings add to \\

Tags: listings

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{maincs}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{secondarycs}{RGB}{255,179,246}
\definecolor{tertiarycs}{RGB}{79,139,87}

\lstset{
language=[LaTeX]TeX,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize,
columns=fullflexible,
breaklines=true,
texcsstyle=*\color{maincs},
texcs={documentclass,begin,end,chapter,section,subsection,label,alpha},
moretexcs=[2]{usepackage,input},
texcsstyle=*[2]{\color{secondarycs!80!black}},
moretexcs=[3]{\n,\,renewcommand,tablename,contentsname,indexname,chaptername,
figurename,listfigurename,listtablename,hyphenation,sin,cos,
index,printindex,item,jobname,date,makeindex,maketitle,title,author,tableofcontents},
texcsstyle=*[3]{\color{tertiarycs}},
inputencoding=utf8,
extendedchars=true,
literate={ö}{\"{o}}1 {ü}{\"{u}}1 {Ş}{\c{S}}1 {ç}{\c{c}}1 {İ}{\.{I}}1 {ı}{\i}1,}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{eqnarray*}
x + y &=& z + t\\
&=& u + 6\\
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

and displaying

[image]

But that I want

[image]

That is, `\\` add to list. What will I do?

Comment: *Which* list are you referring to?

Comment: No difference for me. It must be green, like `moretexcs´

Comment: Ok, I am checking.